# Joining strings with char* expects it the intergal

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I get this error:

> expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

### when I'm using `char*`, because I couldn't get normal strings to work.

oh yeah i have a text.h file with strings

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "text.h"
#include <string.h>

void out(char* output)
{
    std::ofstream logfile ("server.log", std::ios::app);
    if (logfile.is_open())
    {
        logfile << output << "\n";
        logfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << FAIL_OPEN_LOG_MSG_ENG;
    }
    std::cout << output;
}

void log(char* output)
{
    out("[INFO]" << output << "\n");
}

void error(char* output)
{
    std::cout << "[ERROR]" << output << "\n";
}

void warn(char* output)
{
    std::ofstream logfile;
    std::cout << "[WARN]" << output << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    log(LOAD_MSG_ENG);

    log(START_TESTS_MSG_ENG);
    return 0;
}
```

### What I tried

I tried replacing with `char` and it didn't like normal strings, for some reasons.

Comment: `out("[INFO]" << output << "\n")`? That's just not how the streaming output operator `<<` works. You just can't use it on any arbitrary data. You need an actual object which overloads the operator. Like for example an *output string stream* like `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: When most compilers give you an error message, they specify to which line the error message applies. Your question would be easier to understand if you would [edit] it to include this information.

Comment: `FAIL_OPEN_LOG_MSG_ENG` -- `LOAD_MSG_ENG` -- `START_TESTS_MSG_ENG` -- What exactly are these?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: "because I couldn't get normal strings to work" you probably should return to reading a textbook instead of writing code. Programming by guessing does not work.

Comment: It seems you cannot get 'normal strings' and `char*` to work. You should go back to normal strings (I'm assuming you mean `std::string`) since they are far far easier than `char*`, (otherwise what would be the point of them?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"[INFO]" << output << "\n"` is not a valid way to join `char*` strings together.  That operator only works when using classes that implement it, such as `std::ostream`.

For example, in this code:

```cpp
std::cout << "[ERROR]" << output << "\n";
```

`std::cout` is a (reference to a) `std::ostream` object.  So, the compiler calls `std::cout << "[ERROR]"` first, which returns an `std::ostream&` reference to the `std::cout` object.  Then, the compiler calls `<< output` on that object, then calls `<< "\n"` on the object, etc.  So, you are not actually joining the strings together, you are printing them individually, and the stream is internally joining the prints together.

Since there is no `std::ostream` object being used in code like this:

```cpp
out("[INFO]" << output << "\n");
```

You end up with the compiler error, since you can't use `operator<<` in this context.

To do what you are attempting, you would have to use C-style string concatenations instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

void log(char* output)
{
    char *buffer = new char[6 + std:::strlen(output) + 2];

    std::strcpy(buffer, "[INFO]");
    std::strcat(buffer, output);
    std::strcat(buffer, "\n");

    /* Alternatively:
    std::sprintf(buffer, "[INFO]%s\n", output);
    */

    out(buffer);

    delete[] buffer;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a local `std::ostringstream` object in order to use `operator<<`, eg:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

void log(char* output)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "[INFO]" << output << "\n";

    // if you change out() to take a 'const char*' instead,
    // you can then drop this const_cast...
    out(const_cast<char*>(oss.str().c_str()));
}
```

Or, you can use `std::format()` in C++20 and later (or [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev) in earlier versions), eg:

```cpp
#include <format>

void log(char* output)
{
    std::string str = std::format("[INFO]{}\n", output);

    // if you change out() to take a 'const char*' instead,
    // you can then drop this const_cast...
    out(const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()));
}
```

But really, you should be using `std::string` everywhere instead of `char*` in the first place, then you can use its `operator+` to join strings together, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

void out(const std::string& output)
{
    ...
}

void log(const std::string& output)
{
    out("[INFO]" + output + "\n"); // <-- HERE
}

...
```

In general, you should avoid using `char*` strings in C++ at all, except when interfacing with external APIs that require such strings (which is not the case in this example).

Comment: i'll see if it works

Comment: i think it works. Just made it so warn and error functions are the same. Thanks!